# What kind of RPM packages should I use for armv7l

Tags: linux, rpm, arm, cpu-architecture

Suppose I get something like this from uname.

```
Linux localhost 3.8.13-mrvl #12 PREEMPT Wed Aug 12 10:15:36 PDT 2015 armv7l
```

I presume I should use armv7hl packages?

The device is Steam Link. The distro is tricky, the binaries are mostly in Busybox v1.20.1.

Edit: The busybox has rpm.

Comment: iOT/equipment name and model, Unix/Linux version/distribution?

Comment: The device is Steam Link. The distro is tricky, the binaries are mostly in Busybox v1.20.1.

Comment: The busybox does have rpm. I queried a library with it and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can use armv7hl rpms for your armv7l system.